# Count images number and compared the similarity

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am coding a game called "Memory", which contains 8 pairs of images (16 images) in random order. When the game started, 16 of them have to show the same background images. After players click any tile, the tile flip from background images to foreground images. If two foreground images are the same, they stay. If two foreground images are different, they vanish in a few seconds.
For now, I have no idea how to check their similarities. I try to use self.count to count the flipped images number, but cannot work. Please help me. Thank you very very much!

```
import pygame
import random
import time

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((525, 435))

def main():
   pygame.init()
   pygame.display.set_mode((535, 435))
   pygame.display.set_caption('Memory')
   w_surface = pygame.display.get_surface() 
   game = Game(w_surface)
   game.play()
   pygame.quit()

class Game:

   def __init__(self, surface):
      self.surface = surface
      self.bg_color = pygame.Color('black')
      self.FPS = 10
      self.game_Clock = pygame.time.Clock()
      self.close_clicked = False
      self.continue_game = True
      Tile.set_surface(self.surface)
      self.grid_size = 4
      self.grid = []
      self.score = 0
      imgnames = ['./images/' + str(i) + '.jpg' for i in range(1,9)]
      self.images = [pygame.image.load(name) for name in imgnames]
      self.shuffle = self.images + self.images
      random.shuffle(self.shuffle)
      self.create_grid(self.grid_size)

   def create_grid(self, grid_size):
      for row_num in range(grid_size):
         new_row = self.create_row(row_num, grid_size)
         self.grid.append(new_row)     

   def create_row(self, row_num, size):
      tile_height = self.surface.get_height() // size
      tile_width = self.surface.get_width() // (size+1)
      one_row = [ ]
      for col_num in range(size):
         y = row_num * tile_height + 5
         x = col_num * tile_width + 5
         i = col_num*size + row_num
         one_tile = Tile(x, y, tile_width, tile_height, self.shuffle[i], self.surface)
         one_row.append(one_tile)
      return one_row

   def play(self):
      while not self.close_clicked:
         self.handle_events()
         self.draw()
         if self.continue_game:
            self.update()
            self.decide_continue()
         self.game_Clock.tick(self.FPS)

   def handle_events(self):
         events = pygame.event.get()
         for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               self.close_clicked = True
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
               position = event.pos
               for row in self.grid:
                  for tile in row:
                     if tile.rect.collidepoint(position):
                        tile.flip = True

   def draw(self):
      self.surface.fill(self.bg_color)
      self.draw_score()
      for row in self.grid:
         for tile in row:
            tile.draw()
      pygame.display.update()

   def update(self):
      self.score = pygame.time.get_ticks() // 1000

   def decide_continue(self):
      pass

   def draw_score(self):
      score_string = str(self.score)    
      score_font = pygame.font.SysFont('', 48)
      score_fg_color = pygame.Color('white')
      score_image = score_font.render(score_string, True, score_fg_color)
      self.surface.blit(score_image, (430,10))

class Tile:
   def __init__(self, pos_x, pos_y, tile_numx, tile_numy, image, surface):
      self.pos_x = pos_x
      self.pos_y = pos_y
      self.numx = tile_numx
      self.numy = tile_numy
      self.image = image
      self.surface = surface
      self.flip = False
      self.count = 0
      self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (self.pos_x,self.pos_y))

   @classmethod
   def set_surface(cls, surface):
      cls.surface = surface   

   def draw(self):
      x = 0
      y = 0
      i = 0
      if self.flip == False:
         screen.blit(pygame.image.load('./images/bg.jpg'),(self.pos_x,self.pos_y))
      elif self.flip == True:
         while self.count < 2:
            screen.blit(self.image,(self.pos_x,self.pos_y))
            self.count + 1



main()
```

Comment: 2 tiles are equal, if they have the same image. In your code 2 equal tiles share the same image object. Compare the `.image` attribute of the tiles. e.g. if there is a `tileA` and a `tileB`, then they are equal `if tileA.image == tileB.image:`

Comment: what should tileA.image and tileB.image equal to?

Comment: Ummmmmmm hello?

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the attribute `self.count` from  the class `Tile`. It is not needed:

```py
class Tile:
  # [...]

  def draw(self):
      x, y, i = 0, 0, 0
      if self.flip == False:
         screen.blit(pygame.image.load('./images/bg.jpg'),(self.pos_x,self.pos_y))
      elif self.flip == True:
         screen.blit(self.image,(self.pos_x,self.pos_y))
```

---

2 tiles are equal, if they have the same image. In your code 2 equal tiles share the same image object. Compare the `.image` attribute of the tiles. e.g. if there is a `tileA` and a `tileB`, then they are equal if `tileA.image == tileB.image`.

Add a list of the flipped tiles to the class `Game`:

```py
class Game:

   def __init__(self, surface):
      # [...]

      self.flipped = []
```

If the mouse button is pressed, then find the tile which was "clicked" and add it to to flipped tiles:

```py
elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:

    for row in self.grid:
        for tile in row:
            if tile.rect.collidepoint(event.pos) and not tile.flip:
                tile.flip = True
                self.flipped.append(tile)
```

If the number of tile in `self.flipped` is even (`len(self.flipped) % 2 == 0`), then compare the last 2 tiles in the list (`self.flipped[-1], self.flipped[-2]`). Keep equal tiles. If the tiles are not equal (`tileA.image != tileB.image`), then remove them from `self.flipped` and flip them back:

```py
if len(self.flipped) > 0 and len(self.flipped) % 2 == 0:
    tileA = self.flipped[-1]
    tileB = self.flipped[-2] 
    if tileA.image != tileB.image:
        tileA.flip = False
        tileB.flip = False
        self.flipped = self.flipped[:-2]
```

That all can be applied to `handle_events`:

```py
class Game:

   def __init__(self, surface):
      # [...]

      self.flipped = []


  # [...]

  def handle_events(self):
         events = pygame.event.get()
         for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               self.close_clicked = True

            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:

               if len(self.flipped) > 0 and len(self.flipped) % 2 == 0:
                  tileA = self.flipped[-1]
                  tileB = self.flipped[-2] 
                  if tileA.image != tileB.image:
                     tileA.flip = False
                     tileB.flip = False
                     self.flipped = self.flipped[:-2]

               for row in self.grid:
                  for tile in row:
                     if tile.rect.collidepoint(event.pos) and not tile.flip:
                        tile.flip = True
                        self.flipped.append(tile)
```

Note, the tiles do not flip back after a time span, but the flip back when on a new tile is clicked.

---

If you want that the tiles automatically flip back after a time span (e.g. 2 seconds), then I recommend to use a timer [event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html).
A timer can be started by [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer). It can be stopped by passing time 0 to `pygame.time.set_timer()`.

```py
class Game:
   def __init__(self, surface):
      # [...]
      self.flipped = []

   def handle_events(self):
         timer_id = pygame.USEREVENT + 1

         events = pygame.event.get()
         for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               self.close_clicked = True
            elif event.type == timer_id:
               pygame.time.set_timer(timer_id, 0)
               if len(self.flipped) > 0 and len(self.flipped) % 2 == 0:
                  tileA, tileB = self.flipped[-1], self.flipped[-2] 
                  if tileA.image != tileB.image:
                     tileA.flip, tileB.flip = False, False
                     self.flipped = self.flipped[:-2]

            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
               if len(self.flipped) > 0 and len(self.flipped) % 2 == 0:
                  tileA, tileB = self.flipped[-1], self.flipped[-2] 
                  if tileA.image != tileB.image:
                     tileA.flip, tileB.flip = False, False
                     self.flipped = self.flipped[:-2]           
               for row in self.grid:
                  for tile in row:
                     if tile.rect.collidepoint(event.pos) and not tile.flip:
                        tile.flip = True
                        self.flipped.append(tile)

               if len(self.flipped) > 0 and len(self.flipped) % 2 == 0:
                  pygame.time.set_timer(timer_id, 2000) # 2 seconds
               else:
                  pygame.time.set_timer(timer_id, 0)
```

[image]